# Reuse target_compile_options from variable for multiple targets (CMake)

Tags: cmake

I have several build targets and want to set the same set of compile options like this:

```
set(app_compile_options "-Wall -Wextra -Wshadow -Wnon-virtual-dtor \
    -Wold-style-cast \
    -Woverloaded-virtual -Wzero-as-null-pointer-constant \
    -pedantic -fPIE -fstack-protector-all -fno-rtti")

add_executable(foo foo.cpp)
target_compile_options(foo PUBLIC ${app_compile_options})

add_executable(bar bar.cpp)
target_compile_options(bar PUBLIC ${app_compile_options})
```

When compiling I get the following error:

```
error: unrecognized command line option ‘-Wall -Wextra -Wshadow -Wnon-virtual-dtor -Wold-style-cast     -Woverloaded-virtual -Wzero-as-null-pointer-constant     -pedantic -fPIE -fstack-protector-all -fno-rtti’
```

Do I need another format or special syntax to define the compile options in a variable?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In addition of @squaresstkittles's answer, I'd add that you can use interface targets for this purpose:

```
add_library(common INTERFACE)

target_compile_options(common INTERFACE
    -Wall -Wextra -Wshadow -Wnon-virtual-dtor
    -Wold-style-cast
    -Woverloaded-virtual -Wzero-as-null-pointer-constant
    -pedantic -fPIE -fstack-protector-all -fno-rtti
)

target_link_libraries(foo PRIVATE common)
target_link_libraries(bar PRIVATE common)
```

Comment: This looks like the CMake-way, Can I use that also for include?

Comment: @aggsol of course. Simply call `target_include_directories(common INTERFACE ...)`. Also, every property marked PUBLIC will be transitive from targets to targets when linking.

Comment: While @squareskittles answers my question, this actually explains what I am trying to do. So give both an upvote!

Answer (score 5):

You are passing the options as a *single string* by using the quotations. Try removing the quotations (and the `\` line continuation markers) to pass the compile options as a [list](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.12/manual/cmake-language.7.html#cmake-language-lists) instead:

```
set(app_compile_options -Wall -Wextra -Wshadow -Wnon-virtual-dtor
    -Wold-style-cast
    -Woverloaded-virtual -Wzero-as-null-pointer-constant
    -pedantic -fPIE -fstack-protector-all -fno-rtti
)
```